# Report registry info on "DisplayVersion" of a program & compare it to a file on the network

Tags: batch-file, version, export-to-csv

Trying to create a Batch file to check the "DisplayVersion" in the registry, then somehow compare it to a file on the network to see if the program is up to date and report to a CSV file the findings.

I finally had success in showing the "DisplayVersion" and creating a CSV file, but I need more control to compare and report the findings for multiple users. Also not sure if "Revit.exe Properties" would be easier or not.

This is all I have so far, no luck with getting "Revit.exe Properties"

```
@echo on
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Autodesk Revit 2018 SP9" /V DisplayVersion  >C:\INSTALLS\RV.csv

if %DisplayVersion%=="18.3.1.2" goto wait
pause
```

Create CSV file reports user computer info & program "DisplayVersion" to compare what is on file.

Comment: Can you put a list of the output of query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following - no temporary file required:

```
 FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a IN ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Autodesk Revit 2018 SP9" /V DisplayVersion') DO (
   IF "%%a"=="DisplayVersion" SET "DisplayVersion=%%c"
 )
 if %DisplayVersion%=="18.3.1.2" goto wait
 ...
```